# Responsive Image cropping

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have been trying to crop an image for screen sizes below 768px width.  The image should crop equally from the left and right sides.

Here is an Example of the Image at full size (the dimensions of the image are 900px wide by 250px tall.:

[image]

Here is the cropped version I have been trying to create once the screen size is less than 768p wide.  In this version the image is at 320px wide but it should start cropping at 768px:

[image]

Here is the HTML I have been using so far:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLxRs.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 1280px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 768px;
}

.image-container {
    width:100%;
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .image-container {max-width:768px; overflow:hidden;}
}
```

Here's a fiddle I have been using to try and create this:  http://jsfiddle.net/QRLTd/

Is it possible to crop an image from both the left and right sides at the same time?

Comment: Do you want it to crop, or display a second image instead, for smaller resolutions?

Comment: Displaying a smaller image could also work I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QRLTd/4/)**</kbd>

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-container"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height:200px;
}

.image-container {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/H7cpsLK.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    max-width:768px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always absolute position some divs over left and right with a higher z-index value.

I haven't ever used or seen any image cropping via css but you could definitely crop the image in paint or photoshop, upload both images, then swap out the image you want to show with css and possibly make use of media queries.

Answer (score 1):

Responsive images with art direction (selective cropping/scaling) are a tricky area. Luckily  you are just trying to crop towards the center which is a bit easier. Roko's solution seems appropriate for css, but you are still loading the full sized image (slow).

If you want to further optimize and increase your page speed, you should be loading differently sized images so that mobile browsers don't have to download desktop sized or worse, retina display sized, images. The common solution is to swap out your img.src using media query breakpoints and CSS3 and have a pre-cropped version of the image ready to go.

Alternatively, you could use a service such as [Pixtulate](http://www.pixtulate.com) to perform this crop on the fly for each visitor. This would also enable you to crop off center via pre set focal points and your images would be correctly sized for every visitor's screen.